# How to detect java process exit?

Tags: java, bash, process, io, centos

In a java program, I am generating an sh script for use on a centOS machine, which will use sox and lame to decode an MP3 audio file, then apply some gain to the file respectively. Im having some issues getting the Process.waitFor() method to do anything other than hang indefinitely. Here is the code:

```
            try
    {
    // TODO code application logic here
        String reviewPath = "/SomeDirectory/";
        String fileName = "FileName";
        String extension = ".mp3";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("#!/bin/bash\n");
        sb.append("cd " + reviewPath + "\n");
        sb.append("lame --decode " + fileName + extension + "\n"); 
        File script = new File(reviewPath + fileName + ".sh");
        script.createNewFile();
        script.setExecutable(true);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(script);
        writer.write(sb.toString());
        writer.close();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script.getAbsolutePath());
        String line;
        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bri.close();
        while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bre.close();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Done.");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The odd part is that when I run the .sh file it generates by hand, it runs and exits nicely, but when I execute it from a process object in java, it never exits. The exitValue of the process is always "Process has not exited". Ive tried adding set -e to the script, and exit to the end of the script. Short of using the kill command (which I dont really think I can do here) Im at a loss as to what is going on here. Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you generating a shell script in java and then run it instead of performing the entire decoding process in java, contingent on decoding API availability?

Comment: Maybe you need to read out the outputstream ?

Comment: Many processes won't exit until there output buffers have been emptied, that mean you will need to read the contents of the processes input stream until its empty (returns -1)

Comment: For various reasons, to put it simply, these machines are already a maintainance nightmare, but the configuration already requires SOX and LAME, so we opted to use these instead.

Comment: I tried reading from the streams as you can see in my edits above, it didnt change the result at all, the process still doesnt exit.

Comment: But you already close the streams before the call to `p.waitFor()`. Try closing the stream afterwards (preferably in a finally block)

Comment: I think you are better off using the ProcessBuilder API- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html. Look into the example in the javadoc top section which is very close to what you are doing.

Comment: I tried the finally block suggstion by Wim Deblauwo, no effect :(

Comment: I just tried using the process builder api as suggested, but the result is exactly the same, p.waitFor() hangs indefinitely using this code

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(script.getAbsolutePath());
            Process p = pb.start();

Comment: when you do a "ps", what condition is the bash shell process, and the 'lame' process, actually in?  Are they in state "Z" (zombie)?  or "S" (sleeping)?  It would be good to confirm that the non-java part is actually behaving as you think it is.

Comment: I answered the question below :P figured it out with the help of a few of the suggested answers here. Just needed to redirect the STDErr on the process and read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like `while(p.getInputStream().read() != -1);` after starting the process. The buffer will get filled and the process will stop waiting for something (in this case, your program) to read from it to free up space.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The problem here was indeed that the output streams needed to be flushed for the application to exit, but simply reading from the streams is not enough. I used Suresh Koya's suggestion and used the processBuilder api, and redirected the error stream on the process before starting it, and read from the streams. This fixed the issues I was having :D